# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] - os.rename not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename, batch-rename, file-not-found

Feels like I have tried almost everything - and can't for the life of me work out what's going wrong in this code. I've run it on a much simpler example (just os.rename, no manipulations, file_name provided without use of variables etc.) and it worked as expected.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tom/PycharmProjects/Projects/rename files.py", line 35, in <module>
    os.rename(oldfilename, newfilename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\Tom\\Downloads\\oldnameoffile.xlsx' -> 'C:\\Users\\Tom\\Downloads\\newnameoffile.xlsx'
```

Any guidance at all would be amazing - really can't move on from this problem!

Thanks so much

```
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Tom\Downloads")
s_dir = r"C:\Users\Tom\Downloads"

for f in os.listdir():

    [manipulation of filename]
    ...
    ...

    final_file_name_1 = "1_{}.xlsx".format(file_brand)
    final_file_name_2 = "2_{}.xlsx".format(file_brand)

    if file_name[0:1] == "1":
        os.rename(os.path.join(s_dir, f), os.path.join(s_dir, final_file_name_1))
    elif file_name[0:1] == "2":
        os.rename(os.path.join(s_dir, f), os.path.join(s_dir, final_file_name_2))
```

have also tried

```
    final_file_name_1 = "1_{}.xlsx".format(file_brand)
    final_file_name_2 = "2_{}.xlsx".format(file_brand)

    oldfilename = str(s_dir + "\\" + f)

    if file_name[0:1] == "1":
        newfilename = str(s_dir + "\\" + final_file_name_1)
        os.rename(oldfilename, newfilename)
    elif file_name[0:1] == "2":
        newfilename = str(s_dir + "\\" + final_file_name_2)
        os.rename(oldfilename, newfilename)
```

Comment: `os.rename` is working. *your* code does not work because `C:\\Users\\Tom\\Downloads\\oldnameoffile.xlsx` does not exist

Comment: @DeepSpace It seems so, but I as well am confused how that could be. See how the OP gets the "old file name" from the given path and `os.listdir()`.

Comment: @ThomasGardner The only reasomn I can think of is that the new file name contains characters which are not valid and that the error message is just confusing.

Comment: I agree with @glglgl. Windows does not allow use of '{' or '}' in the filename. 

You might want to rename these strings for it to work. 

final_file_name_1 = "1_{}.xlsx".format(file_brand)
final_file_name_2 = "2_{}.xlsx".format(file_brand)

Comment: @ParvBanks These characters shouldn't be really there after `.format()`…

Comment: Also, if you are not fond of using '\\' in the file path, just use a single '/' it works fine.

Comment: do a `print(f)` so we see what it displays.

Comment: @glglgl, ha, so format works with all strings then. I've been using it for print & other actions so far. Interesting. Thanks :)